# When using git submodule update how can you tell it to clone the dependencies with HTTP instead of GIT?

Tags: git

We have port 9418 blocked here so I can't seem to clone with git://xyz.git

Is there a way to make git use HTTP instead?  If I do it manually it works but when I run git submodule update it always wants to use git:

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need to change the configuration variable `submodule.<submodule-name>.url` for each submodule, e.g.:

```
git config submodule.whatever.url http://github.com/nvie/shFlags.git
```

Then when you do `git submodule update`, the `git fetch` which is run in that submodule will use the URL from that configuration variable.

If you want to change `origin` in that submodule, you'll need to take some separate steps:

```
cd whatever
git remote rm origin
git remote add origin http://github.com/nvie/shFlags.git
```

... but if you're not actively working in that submodule, you don't have to worry about that.

The `.gitmodules` file is just used to set the `submodule.<submodule-name>.url` variable when you initialize the submodule.  It's not worth changing unless you want to push a new version of the `.gitmodules` file, and it's good policy to make sure that URLs in the `.gitmodules` file are accessible to everyone who might clone it (e.g. typically you wouldn't commit a `.gitmodules` file with SSH URLs.)

Answer (score 6):

This depends on how the submodules are registered. You must edit the file `.gitmodules` *before* `git submodules init`.

Comment: hmmm not working.  For reference I'm trying to install git-flow.  The .gitmodules is set to http: //github.com/nvie/shFlags.git but when I do git submodule update it still tries to pull from git://github.com/nvie/shFlags.git (scratching head)

Comment: I said: "_before_ `git submodule init`". When you call `init` it will register any submodule to `.git/config` and every change to `.gitmodules` have no effect. You may try to edit `.git/config`, but I dont know, if this will work as expected :X